# Is is possible to get this and scope from \Closure

Tags: php, closures

Does anyone know how to get `this` object and `scope` classname from `\Closure` object?

I tried various methods via reflection etc., but I was not successful. The only options which I found is `var_dump` which dumps the this object, but the scope namespace is still hidden.

Question in code:

```
class A {
    public function makeCallback() {
        return function() {};
    }
}

$a = new A();
$closureWithBound = $a->makeCallback();

var_dump($closureWithBound);
```

which outputs:

```
object(Closure)#6 (1) {
  ["this"]=>
  object(A)#5 (0) {
  }
}
```

**My question is how to get the `this` object from `$closureWithBound` and the static scope of the function (`\A` here).**

EDIT: The scope can not be retrived from the object, as the callback can be declared from static scope, which has still scope, but no object.

Comment: Could you post some code? It's not clear what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I just added an example, any help is welcomed

Comment: Why do you want to do this in the first place? You're trying to do sth weird, if we knew the context we might be able to help...

Comment: I need to get the scope - class (+namespace, ie. full name) where the closure was defined (more exactly bounded). The `this` object is actually irrelevant for me.